# Pandas select with iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1 dimetional DataFrame:

df:

```
   feat1   feat2   feat3  ...  featn
0   0.12   0.002    0.53        0.23
```

I want to filter all the columns that their value is bigger than 0.2:

```
df[df.iloc[0] > 0.2]
```

desired output:

```
    feat3  ...  featn
0    0.53        0.23
```

But I receive an error:

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Comment: Maybe it'd make more sense to work with it as a Series? `row = df.iloc[0]; row[row > 0.2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a boolean slicing, a list/Series matching the length of **rows** is expected, and this filters the rows.

Explicitly subset the **columns**:

```
df.loc[:, df.iloc[0] > 0.2]
```